# Indexing arrays in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have an array:

```
type offsets_type is array (4 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (4 downto 0); 
signal av     : offsets_type;
```

I want to do this, essentially: `av[addr] += 1;`
But this line:

```
 av(to_integer(unsigned(addr))) <= unsigned(av(to_integer(unsigned(addr))) + 1;
```

yields this error:
`to_integer can not have such operands in this context.`

I've also tried using `conv_integer`, but that gives `Wrong type of index` as an error.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of addr? From the syntax, I'd expect it to be an `std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)`, but from the error message, I guess it might be something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. You cast the result of your calculation to an `unsigned`, while the left-hand side is `std_logic_vector`
2. There might be something wrong with the data type of `addr`, but you have not shared that with us.
3. There is a closing parenthese missing in the assignment.

It will be easier if you use "unsigned" in your type definitions. This way, you express that the bit pattern is actually something you want to use in integer arithmetic.

```
type offsets_type is array (4 downto 0) of unsigned (4 downto 0);
signal av     : offsets_type;
signal addr :unsigned(2 downto 0);
```

This will save you a few type conversions:

```
av(to_integer(addr)) <= av(to_integer(addr)) + "1";
```

*Edit:* you did use `ieee.numeric_std.all` didn't you?

Comment: I can't change the type of addr since it is an input, but your answer still helped me. This is what I went with: `av(conv_integer(unsigned(addr))) <= av(conv_integer(unsigned(addr))) + "1";`

Comment: @Pwngulator I would suggest you use the `ieee.numeric_std.all` library (instead of `std_logic_unsigned`). This library has the conversion function `to_integer`.